# how to attach multiple files as e-mail attachment in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

How do I attach multiple files as e-mail attachments in vb.net? I am trying to use a list box where user will select the file and attach which will appear in a listbox. And also I would like to give the option  to delete the attachment also.

Comment: How are you creating the mail? Please show some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx

MailMessage.Attachments is a collection.

Try below for each file in your list

```
message.Attachments.Add(attachment)
```